# How to change the axis value font on a JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, font-size

Just as the title says, if I have a `JFreeChart` (or want to create one) how do I specify the font that is used for the values on the axis? Not the axis label, but the actual values. Specifically I just want to make the font a little bigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [`setTickLabelFont(java.awt.Font font)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setTickLabelFont%28java.awt.Font%29) on the relevant ['Axis'](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html).

Answer (score 15):

For Range Axis

```
 CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
 ValueAxis axis = p.getRangeAxis();
```

For Domian Axis

```
 CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot(); 
 CategoryAxis axis = p.getDomainAxis();
```

then set the font like

```
Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 30);
axis.setTickLabelFont(font)
```

Comment: `setTicklabelFont` -> `setTickLabelFont`